Checking rvalue insert result for std::map gives unexpected results
Test code snippet below (CHECK is macro from test framework and works fine):

typedef std::map<int, double> M;
typedef M::value_type VT;

const VT v0;
M mm;

CHECK(mm.begin() == mm.insert(v0).first);

gives false as result:

ERROR: check is NOT correct CHECK( mm.begin() == mm.insert(v0).first )
values: CHECK( {?} == {?} )

Changing last string to
1)

CHECK(bool(mm.begin() == mm.insert(v0).first));






CHECK(bool(mm.insert(v0).first == mm.begin()));






CHECK(mm.insert(v0).first == mm.begin());






const bool result = mm.insert(v0).first == mm.begin();
CHECK(result);


change nothing: the result is still false
However if I save rvalue of insert result into temporary everything just works:

typedef std::map<int, double> M;
typedef M::value_type VT;

const VT v0;
M mm;

M::iterator it = mm.insert(v0).first;
CHECK(mm.begin() == it);


SUCCESS: check is correct CHECK( mm.begin() == it )
values: CHECK( {?} == {?} )

This behaviour happens only in Release build mode in VS2019 (C++17 or higher) and doesn't happen in any other mode or compiler I've tested.
Could anyone please explain why this is normal or a bug? With C++ standard quotes if necessary.
P.S.: Just to be clear. In my understanding of standard and C++ result is strange because:

std::map::insert does NOT invalidate any iterators (by standard and MS VS implementation). So call order is not an issue (however I tried all 1-4 possible combinations).
bool operator(const std::map::iterator &lhs, const std::map::iterator &rhs) should prolong lifetime of insertion result rvalue iterator(second) and std::map::end() rvalue iterator. So comparison should be well defined.
C++17 does not define any other rules in that case than C++11 or even C++03.


Before C++17 all the examples but the last are undefined behaviour. C++17 and later, I'm not 100% sure, it may be valid, but I recommend to never write code like this anyway.

@Yksisarvinen could you explain why? Operator == for iterators should prolong life time for insert result rvalue iterator (second) and should compare with begin() just fine. What am I missing?

Think about evaluation order. mm.begin() would change after insertion.

I's not about lifetimes, it's about when compiler will execute either side of the operand. Before C++17, it's unspecified if your program would first calculate result of mm.begin() or mm.insert(v0).first, so the result of comparison is undefined. In C++17 I think it's been specified that left hand side will execute first, but IMHO it's still easier to stick to rule of thumb "don't read and write the same object in one statement". Makes the code easier to understand without having to think of the order specifically.

@Yksisarvinen: Nothing changes in C++17 for ==, only @= See Evaluation order

@Jarod42 Thank you for correction. This is exactly why I stick to old rules - so easy to get confused which operator got special treatment and which didn't, it's better to just avoid modifying objects in statements.

@Jarod42 soo second(2.) example should work but does not?

In all cases, mm.begin() has unpredictable value. Might be mm.end() if evaluated before the insertion, or the iterator concerning the inserted element.

Checking rvalue insert result for std::map gives unexpected results  It appears to me that the results are expected, because the result is unspecified.  It is like int i = 0; CHECK(i == ++i); which could be done in this order int i = 0; int j = i; i = i + 1; CHECK(j == i);.  (Since the order of operations is unspecified.)  My rule of thumb is:  don't inspect what is being mutated in the same statement.  Use separate statements.

So unspecified evaluation order of == is an issue?

"C++17 does not define any other rules in that case than C++11 or even C++03." But C++11 does. Pre C++11, that code would be UB (mm is modified and accessed in same expression). After it is just a little better, no UB, but unsequenced ordering make the value unpredictable...

@Jarod42 "mm.begin() would change after insertion" -- Hold on, but for std::map::insert() in particular, no iterators are invalidated. See associative.reqmts.general/175, and this table on cppreference.

@heapunderrun: Before insertion, mm.begin() is mm.end(); after insertion it is the "expected iterator". mm.end() (value before insertion) is still valid value.

@Jarod42 Well, it seems I missed the obvious fact that begin() itself is not an iterator, it's a function that returns an iterator. Then there is no contradiction. Sorry!

What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?

As  Jarod42 said,
mm.begin() has unpredictable value.
For different compilers, the results are different:

For issues with different C++ standard running results,
you can report the problem to the Developer Community and post a link in the comment so that we can follow up.
